# Printing wave like structure

Tags: java, data-structures

Even place digit represent positive slope and odd digit represent negative slope. Need some approach to construct this wave using print function.

[image]

Comment: We can calculate highest and lowest point. But how i print?

Comment: I mean logic!!!!!!!!

Comment: Yes..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes after the code.

```java
public class LineGraf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[]{10, 7, 12, 2, 4, 7, 2, 4, 1, 2, 6, 6, 3, 2, 1, 4, 7, 2, 7, 3, 1, 3, 11, 4, 2, 1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 1, 3, 9, 5, 2, 1, 2, 11, 9, 2, 3, 8,2, 5, 1, 2, 7, 2, 4, 11, 2, 12};
        int rows = 0;
        int tot = 0;
        int cols = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            cols += arr[i];
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                tot += arr[i];
            }
            else {
                tot -= arr[i];
            }
            if (tot > rows) {
                rows = tot;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("rows = %d , cols = %d%n", rows, cols);
        int col;
        int row;
        char[][] graf = new char[rows][cols];
        for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                graf[row][col] = ' ';
            }
        }
        row = 0;
        col = 0;
        char slash;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                slash = '/';
            }
            else {
                slash = '\\';
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i]; j++) {
                graf[row][col++] = slash;
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    row++;
                }
                else {
                    row--;
                }
            }
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                row--;
            }
            else {
                row++;
            }
        }
        for (row = rows; --row >= 0;) {
            for (col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                System.out.print(graf[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

- I initially create a two-dimensional array of `char`. I determine the array dimensions by scanning the input array. In the above code, the input array is variable `arr` and it contains the sample data from your question.
- Then I set every element in the two-dimensional array to a single space.
- Then I place the appropriate character, either forward slash or backslash, accordingly.

Consider the two-dimensional array as a plane in 2D space. Each array element has an X and Y coordinate. The column is the Y coordinate and the row is the X coordinate.

In the end I print the array contents in reverse since row zero, in the array `graf`, must be the last row printed.

This is the output I get when I run the above code.

```
rows = 27 , cols = 240
                                                                                                                                                    /\                                                                                          
                                                                                                                           /\    /\                /  \                                                                                         
                                                                                                                      /\  /  \  /  \              /    \      /\                                                                                
                                                                                                                     /  \/    \/    \            /      \  /\/  \                      /\                                                       
                                                                                                          /\        /                \          /        \/      \                /\  /  \                                                      
                                                                                                         /  \      /                  \        /                  \              /  \/    \                                                     
                                                                                                        /    \  /\/                    \/\    /                    \            /          \                          /\                        
                                                                                                       /      \/                          \  /                      \          /            \                        /  \                       
                                                                                                      /                                    \/                        \        /              \                  /\  /    \                      
                                                                                                     /                                                                \      /                \  /\            /  \/      \                     
                                  /\                                                    /\          /                                                                  \    /                  \/  \          /            \                    
                                 /  \                                                  /  \        /                                                                    \  /                        \        /              \                   
                            /\  /    \                                                /    \/\    /                                                                      \/                          \      /                \                  
                           /  \/      \                                              /        \  /                                                                                                    \/\  /                  \                 
                          /            \                /\                          /          \/                                                                                                        \/                    \                
                         /              \  /\          /  \                    /\  /                                                                                                                                            \  /\           
                        /                \/  \        /    \                  /  \/                                                                                                                                              \/  \          
         /\            /                      \      /      \    /\          /                                                                                                                                                        \         
        /  \          /                        \/\  /        \  /  \/\      /                                                                                                                                                          \        
       /    \        /                            \/          \/      \    /                                                                                                                                                            \       
      /      \      /                                                  \  /                                                                                                                                                              \      
     /        \    /                                                    \/                                                                                                                                                                \     
    /          \  /                                                                                                                                                                                                                        \    
   /            \/                                                                                                                                                                                                                          \   
  /                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          \  
 /                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \ 
/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have your answer, but just for fun here's an alternative solution that makes use of `HashMaps` instead of a grid.

Note that this code works should the wave descend below the starting point, e.g. if the 2nd, down segment was 17 instead of 7.

```
int[] arr = new int[]{10, 7, 12, 2, 4, 7, 2, 4, 1, 2, 6, 6, 3, 2, 1, 4, 7, 2, 7, 3, 1, 3, 11, 4, 2, 1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 1, 3, 9, 5, 2, 1, 2, 11, 9, 2, 3, 8,2, 5, 1, 2, 7, 2, 4, 11, 2, 12};

int cols = 0;
Map<Integer, Integer> colMap = new HashMap<>();
for(int i=0,h=0,d=1; i<arr.length; i++,d=-d,h+=d)
  for(int j=0; j<arr[i]; j++,cols++,h+=d)
    colMap.put(d*cols, h);
        
TreeMap<Integer, List<Integer>> rowMap = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
for(Entry<Integer, Integer> e : colMap.entrySet())
{
    if(!rowMap.containsKey(e.getValue())) 
        rowMap.put(e.getValue(), new ArrayList<>());
    rowMap.get(e.getValue()).add(e.getKey());
}

int rows = 1 + rowMap.firstKey() - rowMap.lastKey();
System.out.printf("rows = %d, cols = %d%n", rows, cols);

char[] line = new char[cols];
Arrays.fill(line, ' ');
for(List<Integer> row : rowMap.values())
{
    for(int i : row) line[Math.abs(i)] = i >= 0 ? '/' : '\\';
    System.out.println(new String(line));
    for(int i : row) line[Math.abs(i)] = ' ';
}
```

Output:

```
rows = 27, cols = 240
                                                                                                                                                    /\                                                                                          
                                                                                                                           /\    /\                /  \                                                                                         
                                                                                                                      /\  /  \  /  \              /    \      /\                                                                                
                                                                                                                     /  \/    \/    \            /      \  /\/  \                      /\                                                       
                                                                                                          /\        /                \          /        \/      \                /\  /  \                                                      
                                                                                                         /  \      /                  \        /                  \              /  \/    \                                                     
                                                                                                        /    \  /\/                    \/\    /                    \            /          \                          /\                        
                                                                                                       /      \/                          \  /                      \          /            \                        /  \                       
                                                                                                      /                                    \/                        \        /              \                  /\  /    \                      
                                                                                                     /                                                                \      /                \  /\            /  \/      \                     
                                  /\                                                    /\          /                                                                  \    /                  \/  \          /            \                    
                                 /  \                                                  /  \        /                                                                    \  /                        \        /              \                   
                            /\  /    \                                                /    \/\    /                                                                      \/                          \      /                \                  
                           /  \/      \                                              /        \  /                                                                                                    \/\  /                  \                 
                          /            \                /\                          /          \/                                                                                                        \/                    \                
                         /              \  /\          /  \                    /\  /                                                                                                                                            \  /\           
                        /                \/  \        /    \                  /  \/                                                                                                                                              \/  \          
         /\            /                      \      /      \    /\          /                                                                                                                                                        \         
        /  \          /                        \/\  /        \  /  \/\      /                                                                                                                                                          \        
       /    \        /                            \/          \/      \    /                                                                                                                                                            \       
      /      \      /                                                  \  /                                                                                                                                                              \      
     /        \    /                                                    \/                                                                                                                                                                \     
    /          \  /                                                                                                                                                                                                                        \    
   /            \/                                                                                                                                                                                                                          \   
  /                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          \  
 /                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \ 
/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \
```